# exception 0x80000000 in android mediaplayer only on android 4.1

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have the following code

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;

....

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

URL is http://currentstream1.publicradio.org:80/

This WORKS perfectly in android 2.2/2.3 OS family.

But in android 4.0.3 and 4.1 I get the following exception

```
Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000

 java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:958)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:918)
    at com.cricbuzz.sample.audio.MainActivity.playOnClickListener(MainActivity.java:116)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

I do not changed any libraries, I just build and debug the same code/settings for both 2.2 and 4.0.3 devices.

so What is the issue?

Comment: Looks like adding the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> fixed my issue!!

Comment: I have that permission in my file but the problem persists :(  More to the point, it's a local playlist (not streaming) on the device with the MP3s downloaded and available.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forgot permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```